# Нахождение нечетных и их количество

Tags: javascript, циклы

На промежутке от 0 до 1000 включительно, для каждого нечетного числа выводите в консоль слово Found. Найдите сумму таких чисел. Если их сумма умноженная на 5 больше 5000, выводите в консоль текст Bigger, в другом случае выводите текст Smaller or equal

Основные требования:
Выводить в консоль слово Found нужное количество раз
Не выводить в консоль значение суммы
Выводить верный текст в конце (Bigger или Smaller or equal)

Сделал такой цикл, но он очень плохо работает. Поясните, что к чему пожалуйста.

```
      for(let i = 0; i<=1000; i++) {
      let sum = 0;
      if(i%2===1) {
         console.log('Found');
         sum+=i;
        if((sum*5)>5000){
         console.log('Bigger');
        }else {
           console.log('Smaller or equal');
       }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю ка-то так

```js
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 0; i<=1000; i++) {
  if(i%2 != 0) {
     console.log('Found');
     sum+=i;
  }
}
     
if((sum*5)>5000){
 console.log('Bigger');
}else {
 console.log('Smaller or equal');
}
```